# IndexError in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code which looks like this

```
 for a in range(0,128):
      for b in range(0,128):
           A = np.zeros((1,3))
           B = np.zeros((1,3))
           for i in range(0,3):
                A[i] = I[a,b,i]
```

However, it gives me the following error

```
 A[i] = I[a,b,i]
 IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Thank You, in advance.

Comment: `A` contains only one row, so `A[1]` is going to raise an IndexError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.zeros((1, 3))` creates an array with one "row" and three "columns":

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]]) # note "list of lists"
```

If you want to index straight into the columns, you can simply create the array as:

```
A = np.zeros(3)
```

and get

```
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Then your loop will work as currently written.

Alternatively, you will need to index into the row first:

```
for index in range(3):
    A[0, index] = ...
```

Comment: numpy arrays are indexed `A[0, index]`.